# How to parse an arbitrary text file using only the MySQL command line client?

Tags: mysql, command-line

From the MySQL command line client is there a way to count the words in a given text file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer to this question, the trick is the following line of code:

```
load data infile "PATH_TO_FILE" into table TABLE_NAME lines terminated by ' '
```